# Jekyll loops for posts and other section

Tags: ruby, blogs, jekyll

I use Jekyll for more than 3 month now. I have made several blogs with it, but I have one question I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

In order to render all your posts , all the markdown files in the _posts, I use a for loop like this one for instance :

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {{post.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to do the same with my projects. I created a _projects folder and tried to render them by using :

```
{% for project in site.projects %}
   {{project.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

But Jekyll doesn't seem to recognize the _projects folder. What should I do to get the same results ?

Answer (score 6):

This is not the way custom post types work in Jekyll. You can however put a `_posts` directory in another directory and build custom *categories* this way.

Suppose you would have your projects organized under `projects/_posts`, then your template would have to look something like this:

```
{% for post in site.categories.projects %}
  {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Found it in [Jekyll's Github Issues](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/598)

Answer (score 1):

Now we have [Jekyll Collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/)

> *"Add the following to your site’s `_config.yml` file, replacing
>   `my_collection` with the name of your collection."*

For example you should add:

```
collections:
- projects
```

Then of course, you could use it in your template in the most easy way:

```
{% for project in site.projects %}
   {{project.title}}
{% endfor %}
```